# Failed to start watch mode at metro jest-haste-map

Tags: android, react-native, yarnpkg, metro-bundler

I'm receiving an error in metro build in my react native app each time I try to start my android app.

I have added the package of watchman and also I deleted all node_modules folder and re-installed all the packages and still receiving the same error

Error message:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Failed to start watch mode.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\user_id\Documents\projectX\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:1059:24)**
```